# Retrain Azure Custom Speech model with additional data

Tags: speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

Is there a way to re-train an Azure Custom Speech model with additional text data? At the moment the only way is create a new text data source with the old data + new data and train a new model every time.

My question is regarding using a text file (related text) and not audio + text. The text file improves the accuracy of recognition greatly but has a 200 MB limit. While this limit might do to start with, it will quickly seem too less especially for an enterprise application.